# Django built-in password reset, what's wrong with my urls?

Tags: django

Everyone seems to point to this guide for easy plug-in password reset:
http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html

So from what I've read, if you want it to function then the urls are all you need are 4 urls defined:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 . . . 
    url(r'^user/password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/reset/done/'}, name="password_reset"),
        (r'^user/password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
        (r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/done/'}),
        (r'^user/password/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
 . . .
)
```

This does not seem to be working as I'm still getting the infamous

> NoReverseMatch at /user/password/reset/

with this:

```
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'NA', u'token': u'3ps-749165b2b39d4168f97f'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$']
```

Is there something depreciated already with the guide I put a link to at the top? Should I be importing anything to the urls.py file?

Comment: which url are you calling?
at what stage does it fail?

Answer (score 4):

Your url pattern is using `uidb36`, but your reverse call is looking for `uidb64`. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.6/#django-contrib-auth-password-reset-uses-base-64-encoding-of-user-pk) for more information on this change in 1.6.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it. But this is the last straw. I will never develop for Django anymore and switch to Pyraminds. They keep depreciating EVERYTHING, what's the point of sticking with a language that's going to completely make my old code obsolete and make me feel like a rookie after each tiny update??